# How to get value of a cell in row data bound event? and how to check if a cell is empty?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, webforms, rowdatabound

I'm using sqldatasource and a **GridView**.
I want to get the value of a cell from the GridView in the `RowDataBound` event?, Because I can't use `e.RowIndex`.

How to check in the updatng event if a cell is empty?
I used `if != null`, but it didn't worked so I need to check if it's empty.

thanks

Comment: add some sample code to show what u have done with code

Comment: I'm not home and I don't have the code but I took the value from the texbox control of the cell for the gridview then chekc if is !=null ! . And for the first I don't know what shall I do

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In the RowdataBound Event, you can get the value of a cell from gridview using the following Code:

[**1**]//getting username rfom particular row

```
string servicename = Convert.ToString(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "Name"));
```

In the RowUpdating event, you can check if cell is empty or not, by using following code:

```
string servicename = grdvw_showdetails.DataKeys[row.RowIndex][1].ToString();
```

Above code uses Datakey in the row updating event. if you don't want to use the datakey, the code to check specific cell is empty or not is

```
 TextBox txtaname = (TextBox)row.FindControl("txt_updname");

 if(txtaname.text != null)
```

---

**EDIT:**

This answer is excellent. However I would like to add a bit of a comment. When checking row cells data within `RowDatabound` event, the row's `DataItem`'s ItemArray property is not directly accessible. So when we do  something like this, it's pointless : `string val = e.Row.Cells[2].Text.ToString();` and throws an error.

That's where the first line of this answer comes in.[**1**]

Following screen shows the tree/hierarchy of the Row's underlying properties when you do a watch at debug mode.

[image]

Comment: +1 to OP and @giri. I don't know what I would do if it wasn't for SO community. It's good to be born later it seems ;) when people have gone through these walls and found great answers :D I just udpated your answer to give some visual impact, if you don't mind.