# how to read column and row value in rowbound

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can I read a specific row and column in rowbound? If I had 2 values in my gridview, I want to read the per row and column in rowbound

code here

```
 protected void gvModal_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            string idd = gvModal.DataKeys[e.Row.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
            string qa = "select Date_Issued, Quantity, Unit FROM Issuance_Consumables";
            GridView gvDet = (GridView)e.Row.FindControl("gvIssuance");

            gvDet.DataSource = GetData2(qa);
            gvDet.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

DateIUssued, Quantity and Unit will vary from the "Model","Company", etc from the string "idd"

Comment: Check [get the value of a cell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10295401/how-to-get-value-of-a-cell-in-row-data-bound-event-and-how-to-check-if-a-cell-i). I think this might help.

Comment: RowDataBound is fired for each row and that row controls are accessible in RowDataBound. To get the previous row  GridViewRow prevrow = GridView1.Rows[e.Row.RowIndex - 1];

Comment: Are you using nested GridView?

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this, You need to get your respective cell value.

string value = e.Row.Cells[2].Text;

You can get the values like this and you can proceed.